# Nginx server response time is unexpectedly high for one in hundreds of requests

Tags: nginx, http-live-streaming, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, response-time

I'm using Nginx to serve .ts files for live streaming (HLS). Everything works fine but there is a problem with the response time of the files. Occasionally, some .ts files received from the server have unexpected high response time which is problematic in our use case.

I have used a python script in order to find what's the problem.
[output of python script printing response time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gepdr.png)

In this screenshot full response time is the time between the request is sent and the full response is received. The second parameter shown is the time between a request being sent and a response being received. (I've used response.elapsed.total_seconds() in requests package of python). In slow requests full response time is higher but response.elapsed.total_seconds() is OK. (And by higher I mean 3-4 times the average response time.)

On top of this problem, I have another problem in which both response time (response.elapsed.total_seconds()) and full response time is high. This case happens less frequently (maybe once in 200 requests) and response times are much higher than in the first case.

I should mention that I have some other machines in front of this machine to proxy and cache files. But doesn't matter if I request the cache machines or the main one. The result is the same.

Here's my nginx config:

```
user  root;
worker_processes  16;

worker_rlimit_nofile 1000000;

master_process on;

pid        /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  500000;
    accept_mutex off;
    multi_accept off;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush on;

    server_tokens off;

    keepalive_timeout  150;
#    keepalive_requests 5;

    aio on;
    gzip on;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 4k;
    client_body_buffer_size 1k;
    client_max_body_size 1k;
    client_body_timeout 12;
    client_header_timeout 12;
    send_timeout 10;
    tcp_nodelay       on;
    sendfile_max_chunk 1m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    vhost_traffic_status_zone shared:vhost_traffic_status:10m;
    underscores_in_headers on;
    recursive_error_pages on;

    server {
        listen 80 backlog=10000000;
        location /tmp {
            access_log /cache/nginx.log main;
            types {
                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
                video/mp2t ts;
            }
            alias /cache/hls;
            add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
     }
}
```

I couldn't find anything about this problem until now. Hope I could find an answer here.

Comment: There is no information to go on here - screenshots of the output of unknown code are not helpful; the nginx config and nginx logs would help. However, the question is better suited to serverfault.com

Comment: Actually there is nothing fancy with the nginx logs. Everything is normal. And yeah I should've posted my nginx config. However again there is nothing fancy with the config too. I will edit the post and post my nginx config.

Comment: The logs would at least confirm the problem is nginx and not your local network and/or test script... `However, the question is better suited to serverfault.com` <- note this please.

Comment: If you can turn the debug log of nginX - it will show you a deeper insight into where exactly is the bottleneck. Just keep in mind that it will be huge - so don't keep it running for too long.